# JOOQ. How to record to DB with insertInto() a multiple fields in one transaction

Tags: java, sql, transactions, jooq, insert-into

I need to create **one transaction** and execute **.insertInto()** for multiple unspecified fields of certain tables. I have a problem that transaction is runned successful, but no records is stored. I think the root clause is not proper execution of **.insertInto()** method or **DSLContext** has fail interaction with the wrapper **Configuration**. I will be very greatful for any suggestion.

I have two methods in two classes (tables processing and DAL). Fisrt for transaction creation and sending to DAL-class fields to insert. Second, DAL-class, for inserting a new field.

```
    public Boolean insertToMainDB(List<TableForMainDb> mainTables) throws AppDataAccessLayerException {
    Boolean InsertTransactSuccessFlag = false;
    try {
        TransactionalCallable <Boolean> transactional = new TransactionalCallable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean run(Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
                for (TableForMainDb table : mainTables) {
                    table.getRecorder().recordToDB(table, configuration);
                 }
                return true; 

            }   
        };
        InsertTransactSuccessFlag = context.transactionResult(transactional);
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        throw new AppDataAccessLayerException(ex);
        }
    return InsertTransactSuccessFlag;
    }
```

Second method in DAL class:

```
    public boolean recordToDB(TableForMainDb mainDBtable, Configuration configuration) {

    boolean InsertFlag = false;

    for (String key : mainDBtable.fields.keySet()){
        //using(configuration).
        insertInto (
                             table(mainDBtable.getTableName())
                            ,field(mainDBtable.fields.get(key).getFieldName())
                            ,value(mainDBtable.fields.get(key).getFieldValue())
                ).attach(configuration);

        InsertFlag = true; //TBD    
            }
    return InsertFlag;

}
```

Transaction runs successful, but records is not inserted to DB.

In Debug mode I see that objects for **DSLContext** and **Configuration** are full and contain record to insert date (fields).
The dumps is below. The **transactional** field = false in context.

**Configuration**
    DefaultConfiguration [
    connected=true,
    transactional=true,
    dialect=POSTGRES,
    data={org.jooq.configuration....},
    settings=...

**DSLContext**
    DefaultConfiguration [
    connected=true,
    transactional=false,
    dialect=POSTGRES,
    data={},
    settings=...

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling [`Query.execute()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#execute--) on your [`Insert`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Insert.html) statement

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Lukas for the comment and for the great JOOQ.

we implement insert as

```
    .insertInto(Table<Record>, Fields[], Object[] ).execute()
```

we prepared **fields** as array of Field[]  and **values** as array of Object[] and than pass it to **.insertInto()**

**fieldsAndValuesObject** it is object of wrapper class for fields and values (add/get/set).

```
            DSL.using(configuration).insertInto(DSL.table(tableName), 
                                        fieldsAndValuesObject.getArrayAllFields())
                                        .values(fieldsAndValuesObject.getArrayAllValues()
                                        )
                                        .execute();
```

Comment: Hi there. Is this your solution? Or did you mean to edit your question? I'm not sure if you still need any help...

Comment: Hi Lukas, yeap, it works, I was a bit wonder that I can call .insertInto() with array of Fields[] as parameter, maybe it will be useful to add to doc.

Comment: Hmm, [it's right there in the Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#insertInto-org.jooq.Table-org.jooq.Field...-). What's missing, according to you?